# Why is the rendering object moving in the ARCore Location example?

Tags: android, location, arcore

I'm using ARCore Location Example from GitHub(https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location/tree/master/examples/sceneform). I made an object with fixed coordinates, but the rendering object keeps moving not stable. I was copy and paste the code. I did not change anything. Why object moving?

Comment: I had same issue. But as per my search, Android Ar Core  and Ar scene library is not stable yet for world coordinates (Location service + ArCore). https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/119
So,maybe appoly's library will give update when google will give update on arcore.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Drift.

> As ARCore’s environmental understanding updates throughout an AR experience, virtual objects can appear to drift away from where they were placed. This can impact your app's realism and user experience.

This happens because the information processes from accelerometer, gyroscope, etc maybe not be exactly, cause for example from small movements that are not recognize.

To avoid this ARCore give the solution to use Anchors.